# javascript : How to handle chage event handler for multiple checkbox in single function and print whick checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

## Description

i have multiple checkbox and want handle all checkbox click event in single handler function
and want to know which is checked.i tried below code and not working

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox1').addEventListener('change', changeHandler("Checkbox1"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox2').addEventListener('change', changeHandler("Checkbox2"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox3').addEventListener('change', changeHandler("Checkbox3"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox4').addEventListener('change', changeHandler("Checkbox4"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox5').addEventListener('change', changeHandler("Checkbox5"));
});
function changeHandler(checkboxs) {
    //Do Something...maybe another function showAlert(), for instance
    if (checkboxs.checked) {
        console.log("Checkbox checked");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Checkbox unchecked");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    Checkbox1: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox4: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4">
  </div>
  <div>
    Checkbox5: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're calling the function in your `addEventListener` rather than assigning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you are *calling* `changeHandler` rather than assigning it to the listener. You can fix this by changing each one to an anonymous function that in turn calls the handler:

```
document.querySelector('#Checkbox1').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox1"));
```

Which will lead you to your next problem which is that you are passing a string, eg. 'Checkbox1',  but then trying to check if the element is checked directly on this string which will always return false (`'Checkbox1'.checked === undefined`). To fix that you will need to use the passed string to query the element first:

```
function changeHandler(checkboxs) {
    const checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxs)
    
    if (checkbox && checkbox.checked) {
        console.log("Checkbox checked");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Checkbox unchecked");
    }
}
```

Final working example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox1').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox1"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox2').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox2"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox3').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox3"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox4').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox4"));
    document.querySelector('#Checkbox5').addEventListener('change', () => changeHandler("Checkbox5"));
});

function changeHandler(checkboxs) {
    const checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxs)

    if (checkbox && checkbox.checked) {
        console.log("Checkbox checked");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Checkbox unchecked");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    Checkbox1: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox4: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4">
  </div>
  <div>
    Checkbox5: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But you can avoid all of the repetition, as well as the use of anonymous functions by using event delegation (see [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) for discussion). A single listener is attached to the `document` and the implicitly passed `event` is checked, in this case for `type === 'checkbox'`, if it satisfies our conditions we operate on it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});

function changeHandler(event) {
  if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log(`Checkbox with id: ${event.target.id} checked`);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Checkbox unchecked");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    Checkbox1: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3">
  </div>
    <div>
    Checkbox4: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4">
  </div>
  <div>
    Checkbox5: <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Great explanation and working perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.